# Create properties using lambda getter and setter

Tags: python, lambda, properties

I have something like this:

```
class X():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name = None

    def _process_value(self, value):
        # do something
        pass

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def set_name(self, value):
        self.__name = self._process_value(value)

    name = property(get_name, set_name)
```

Can I replace `get_name` and `set_name` using lambda functions?

I've tried this:

```
name = property(lambda self: self.__name, lambda self, value: self.__name = self.process_value(value))
```

but compiler doesn't like my setter function.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to make the property definitions more obscure.  What's the point of replacing simple functions with lambdas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your problem is that lambda's body must be an expression and assignment is a statement (a strong, deep distinction in Python). If you insist on perpetrating `lambda`s you'll meet many such cases and learn the workarounds (there's usually one, though not always), such as, in this case:

```
name = property(lambda self: self.__name, 
                lambda self, value: setattr(self, 
                                            '_X__name',
                                            self.process_value(value)))
```

i.e. use the built-in `setattr` (which is a function and thus acceptable in a `lambda`'s body) rather than assignment (which is a statement and thus unacceptable in a `lambda`'s body).

You also need to perform the name-mangling for the dual-underscore attribute manually (changing `__name` to `_X__name` as you're in class X) where the attribute name is presented as a quoted string, as it must be in `setattr`, as the Pyhon compiler only does the name mangling in question for suitable identifiers, not for string literals.

Comment: I have one more issue there. setattr works only for "_name" not "__name".

Comment: Ah yes, you need to manually perform the mangling as it's a quoted-string -- let me edit accordingly!

Answer (score 3):

If you are extending a `list`, you can also use `__setitem__`, like this:

```
class Position(list):
    def __init__(self,x=0, y=0, z=0):
        super(Position, self).__init__((x,y,z))

    x = property(lambda self: self[0],
                 lambda self,value: self.__setitem__(0, value))
    y = property(lambda self: self[1],
                 lambda self,value: self.__setitem__(1, value))
    z = property(lambda self: self[2],
                 lambda self,value: self.__setitem__(2, value))
```